# reactive-banana: How to create an AddHandler?

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, reactive-banana

I'm currently trying to get to know FRP through Heinrich Apfelmus' [reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana), which seems to be a quite well documented and simple library, compared to the other ones I've looked at.

However, I can't wrap my head around the [AddHandler](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.4.3.0/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Implementation.html#t%3aAddHandler) type. Let's say I want to use [GLFW](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b-0.1.0.1) to get mouse button clicks so that I have something like `eMouseButton :: Event ()`. Looking at the examples, it seems that I'd somehow have to use [fromAddHandler](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/0.4.0.0/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Implementation.html#v%3afromAddHandler), but I have no idea how to assemble that `AddHandler` argument. I think I'll have to use `newAddHandler` somehow, but how?

I guess an example of how to connect `reactive-banana` to something other than `wx` would help a lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`newAddHandler` is used like this:

```
do (addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler
   ...
```

`addHandler` is the AddHandler to pass to `reactive-banana`, and `fire` is a function of type `a -> IO ()` (where *a* is your event type) that triggers the event.

For instance, you would likely install `fire` as the callback to GLFW's mouse-button event, like so:

```
registerMouseButton :: IO (Event MouseButton)
registerMouseButton = do
  (addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler
  setMouseButtonCallback $ \button _ -> fire button
  fromAddHandler addHandler
```

(I'm not experienced with GLFW, so I'm not sure what the second argument to `setMouseButtonCallback`'s callback is — if it's important, you'll need to amend this implementation appropriately.)

An `AddHandler` is just a function which takes a callback — `a -> IO ()` — and registers it for the event in question; it then *returns* (from within `IO`) an `IO ()` action used to *deregister* this handler, making the [complete definition of `AddHandler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/reactive-banana/latest/doc/html/Reactive-Banana-Implementation.html#t%3aAddHandler) read as follows:

```
type AddHandler a = (a -> IO ()) -> IO (IO ())
```

So where does `newAddHandler` come in? Simple: `newAddHandler` maintains a list of handlers for an event, and activates them when `fire x` is executed.

You don't need `newAddHandler` if, like GTK+ and many other common toolkits, your toolkit already has facilities to register and deregister multiple event handlers; if it does, you should write your own implementation of an `AddHandler`. But if all it supports is a single callback, you should use `newAddHandler`.

Note that you never need to expose `AddHandler`s to the FRP-using code itself; they're just internal glue used to create `Event`s from external inputs.

Comment: Finally it clicked! Thank you.

Comment: Oops — the last time I used reactive-banana with a GUI toolkit, I wrote a short (~30 line) binding to GTK+, which does have this functionality; I haven't really used wxWidgets, but assumed that it did too, because implementing an `AddHandler` for GTK+ was so natural :) Upon further investigation, it doesn't; I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @bzn: Basically, wxWidgets didn't offer a way to deregister specific event handlers again, that's why I had to use the `newAddHandler` utility.

Comment: Can somebody help me understand what newAddHandler is doing under the hood? may be the author @HeinrichApfelmus? i don't quiet understand the `let register handler` construction inside the do block, I can't figure out how the 'handler' is smuggle inside the let / do block, have kind of intuition that it comes from "outside" through the call of `register addHandler putStrLn` then it fires all the newAddHandler code responsible for building addHandler a (all names are taken from original library) -> may it a question for a new thread in Stack?

Comment: I think I made it - a confirmation would be nice. Thanks to Haskell reference transparency so, `addHandler _is_ AddHandler register` then `register _something_  **pattern match with** register _handler_ and _handler_ **becomes** _something_ (i.e. putStrLn if you stay with the library example). It's coming from outside as in my first thought.