# reactive-banana GLFW event register example

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, glfw, reactive-banana

In a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631816/reactive-banana-how-to-create-an-addhandler) there has been given a quasi-code example, that is, supposedly, easy to fix:

```
registerMouseButton :: IO (Event MouseButton)
registerMouseButton = do
(addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler
setMouseButtonCallback $ \button _ -> fire button
fromAddHandler addHandler
```

I could not fix it so far.  Can somebody provide a snippet of a functional code that registers a key event?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [GLFW-b](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b-1.4.8.0), you can do this:

```
registerMouseButton :: Window -> MomentIO (Event MouseButton)
registerMouseButton window = do
    (mouseEvent, fireMouseEvent) <- newEvent   
    liftIO $ setMouseButtonCallback window $ Just (\_ mouseButton _ _ -> fireMouseEvent mouseButton)
    return mouseEvent
```